# Webpack: getting this error: build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

When running Webpack, I get the following error:

./src/css/main.css 3.62 KiB {0} [not cacheable] [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/css/main.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
...
      accumulator[normalizedUrl] = { ...accumulator[normalizedUrl],
                                     ^^^
...

webpack.config.js:

```
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
         test: /\.css$/i,
         use: ['css-loader']
        }
      ]
    }
```

css:

```
    body {
      background-color:purple;
    }
```

js:

```
    import css from '../css/main.css';
```

on js file, if I enter

```
    import '../css/main.css';
```

I get the same error.

I'd appreciate your help please.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by upgrading node.